# Hibernate Inheritance Update problem

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have the following Pojos:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMUNICATION")
@Audited
public class CommunicationPojo
    implements Serializable
{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSMISSION_TYPE", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private TransmissionTypePojo transmissionType;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSMISSION_TYPE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Audited
public abstract class TransmissionTypePojo
    implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
        private long id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy= "transmissionType")
    private CommunicationPojo communication;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSMISSION_TYPE_AS2")
@Audited
public class TransmissionTypeAS2Pojo
    extends TransmissionTypePojo
    implements Serializable
{}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSMISSION_TYPE_MAIL")
@Audited
public class TransmissionTypeMailPojo
    extends TransmissionTypePojo
    implements Serializable
{}
```

If if saved a communication instance with a TRANSMISSION_TYPE_MAIL instance, changed the communication instance, so that it contains a TRANSMISSION_TYPE_AS2 instance instead of a TRANSMISSION_TYPE_MAIL instance and updated the communication, hibernate would insert an entry in TRANSMISSION_TYPE_AS2 but would not delete the old entry in TRANSMISSION_TYPE_MAIL. 
Is there a possibility to delete the old entry automatically by hibernate or must I delete it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

You may add [`orphanRemoval=true`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#orphanRemoval%28%29) to the OneToOne annotation of `communication`.

Note that it has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: I added orphanRemoval=true but the TRANSMISSION_TYPE_AS2 entry still exists. Hibernate does not do a delete-operation on the TRANSMISSION_TYPE_AS2-table. I also added the hashcode- and equals-function to the transmission_type-pojo...

Comment: It should work, at least if you're working on attached entities. If you make all this on detached entities and then use saveOrUpdate or merge, it won't work. See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5559.